# Is there a way to stream data from C to Node.js

Tags: c, node.js, stream, streaming, node-streams

I have done a research on this and possible solutions I have found is a few:

- having writing to a file from C and reading the file with a Node.js stream. Here, I have some doubts. I need to have more knowledge about Node streams and make sure if they can be used this way. I need to keep the stream on the file open even if the end of file is reached and continue when the new data (possibly as lines) appended to the file.
- Using [Node.js C/C++ Addons](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/addons.html). But it seems more complicated than the first option with first approach.
- Using [Node.js File System Class FSWatcher (File System Watcher)](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) and its methods like [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) and [fs.watchFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener). But it **does not have a way to give the new data written to the file**, and the have their own [Caveats](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_caveats) and performance problems(See the Note at the and of [fs.watchFile](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener) section), respectively. Maybe using them in combination with [fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) and [reading from a position in the file](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_read_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)  can give a way to achive what I want to do. But this seems rather complicated.

Is there a way to stream data from C to Node.js uninterruptedly unless I stop it programmatically?

Comment: what about Message Queues (ie, zeromq), or linux pipes / sockets ?

Comment: Yes, just open a pipe/socket?

Comment: It sounds like you'd rather have a socket connection between the two.  The node.js app can then just be event driven and it will be notified whenever there is data waiting on the socket.  Or you could use stdio.

Comment: Ok, it seems I need more research on the C part, regarding your pointings. I am a Node.js developer I know about webscokets/http and Nodejs streams, but have little or no knowledge on the C part, it will be the main responsibility of another developer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on these possibilities a bit more?

Comment: I think  I should open a socket from Node.js part (and probably with `net.Socket`) and listen to it for the C program writes to it.